# PHP : Sometimes CURL not return any content

Tags: php, curl

When I try to get content using CURL but many time does not return any value..

**Note :** I am tested on same URL

CURL CODE

```
function curltest($url){

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$agents = array(
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100508 SeaMonkey/2.0.4',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; da-dk) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1'
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agents[array_rand($agents)]);

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 10";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); // ADD THIS
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
curl_close($ch);
$output = file_get_contents($url);
}
return $output;

}
```

Please give any suggestion OR tell me if any changes required in above code

Answer (score 0):

see here to get all options in curl [php curl options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Different sites using different type of client validation. If your curl fails to valid there site, it may return nothing.

Comment: I already see that page .......... I only want to know any additional option OR any changes required in above code or not

Comment: You can use these options to make your curl perfect CURLOPT_REFERER, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_REFERER, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.